# Trouble updating dplyr package in r

Tags: r

I am having trouble updating several packages in rStudio. My Macbook is up to date and my rStudio is also up to date.

Please help me figure out how to fix it.

Kind Regards

Here is a snippit of my rStudio terminal trying to update the "dplyr" package

```
>install.packages("dplyr")

There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
dplyr 0.8.0.1  0.8.5              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘dplyr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dplyr_0.8.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1378766 bytes (1.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘dplyr’ ...
** package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang++  -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DRCPP_DEFAULT_INCLUDE_CALL=false -DCOMPILING_DPLYR -DRCPP_USING_UTF8_ERROR_STRING -DRCPP_USE_UNWIND_PROTECT -DBOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/BH/include" -\                                                    ^
1 warning and 5 errors generated.
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/dplyr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dplyr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/p5/7cr4ncpx38s_0trbs9966_8w0000gn/T/RtmpHMQzDX/downloaded_packages’
>
```

Comment: Unless critical to use 0.8.5, answer no to "install from source" for the time being. Retry in a few days when the binary will be available

Comment: Please note, I had to take out a lot of the code in between "downloaded 1.3 MB" and "* installing *source* package ‘dplyr’ ..." as github wouldn’t allow it to be posted

Comment: I just need to update it to 0.8.2 to do further coding is there away to update it?

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/ . You will need to compile C++ code to install dplyr from source, and there seems to be something wrong (or absent) from your setup, hopefully the article would help

Comment: You seem to be running R 3.4, so head to https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos-before-3.5.0/

Comment: Alternatively, try install.packages("remotes") ; remotes::install_version("dplyr", version = "0.8.2") (or 0.8.4)

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: @JimChen 10.15.3

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately I did try but it just says Error in package_find_repo(package, repos) : 
  couldn't find package 'dplyr' @Aurèle ill have a look at the link you sent and  try that out

Comment: I encounter same problems few days ago, try to install `gcc` with `brew` in terminal and try again.